# Modifying jQuery ajax request Connection header

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, jquery-1.3

I'm trying to modify the Connection header with the following code with no success

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: URL,
    async: boolVariable,
    beforeSend: function(xhr)   
    {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    }   
})
```

The request headers via Firebug show:

```
Connection  keep-alive
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Any odd bugs/problems with setting this particular header known? Or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the standard [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method) you are not allowed to set the *Connection* header. It will terminate the set header. Also if you try this in webkit the console will output *Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"* So it looks like you will not be able to do what you want on the client side.

Comment: I even checked headers on w3. Just not xmlhttprequest obj. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no work around as well ?